# Dual-purpose accessor code refactor using define_method

Tags: ruby, methods

To achieve a DSL like attribute assignment,a dual-purpose accessor was utilized. However, I was seeking a way to refactor the obvious code duplication.

```
class Layer

   def size(size=nil)
     return @size unless size 
     @size = size
   end

   def type(type=nil)
     return @type unless type 
     @type = type
   end

   def color(color=nil)
     return @color unless color 
     @color = color
   end

end
```

I was thinking define those method in a class method by using `define_method` along with other methods to get/set the instance variables. However, the dilemma is how can I access the instance from class method?

```
def self.createAttrMethods
     [:size,:type,:color].each do |attr|
       define_method(attr) do |arg=nil|
           #either use instance.send() or 
           #instance_variable_get/set
           #But those method are instance method !!
       end 
     end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `define_method` block, `self` will be pointing to current instance of class. So use `instance_variable_get`.

```
class Foo
  def self.createAttrMethods
    [:size,:type,:color].each do |attr|
      define_method(attr) do |arg = nil|
        name = "@#{attr}"
        return instance_variable_get(name) unless arg
        instance_variable_set(name, arg)      
      end
    end
  end

  createAttrMethods
end

f = Foo.new
f.size # => nil
f.size 3
f.size # => 3
```